# XLRD unsupported format found

Tags: python, django, django-models, xlrd

Using version 0.9.2 of XLRD and python 2.7 on WINDOWS...

Im creating a temporary file and then reading the file using XLRD

```
data = self.excel_file
path = default_storage.save('temp/temp.xls', ContentFile(data.read()))
tmp_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(tmp_file)
```

As soon as I try and open the XLS file it returns with the error

```
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format found '\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x00\x00'
```

So I guess the file is not saved correctly above or something. Not sure what do do about this, as this works when uploading the file with django admin in a file field.

Where saving the file like this in python to django model creates the issues above:

```
from django.core.files import File

p = Foo()
p.excel_file.save(file_name, File(data))
p.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this could be a unicode issue. I'm guessing there is non-ASCII characters in your strings? try Using `.encode("utf-8")` with your strings when you save them to the xls.

**EDIT**: this was a guess, after more investigation by @Harry looks like it's not the correct solution.

**EDIT 2**: If the file cannot be opened by Excel as discussed below then the data itself is probably the problem.

Comment: Yes - it's worth a shot.

Comment: That gives this: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Harry why not have a look at what's in the tmp file?

Comment: mmm, seens I cant open it with excel.. must be that then

Comment: @Harry - yes, it looks like the error has a different source. I edit my answer to reflect that possibility.